# Remove items from List<string> that exist in Substring of CheckedListBox items

Tags: c#, list, winforms, linq, checkedlistbox

In a WinForms application, I have a CheckedListBox (lst_files), and a variable files of type List which is populated with simple paths of text files.  For example purposes, I will use only one item in files

```
List<string> files = new List<string>() { "C:\\migration\\TestFiles\\New Text Document.txt" };
```

Before I populate lst_files, I remove all items from files that already exists in lst_files, by doing

```
files.RemoveAll(x => lst_files.Items.Contains(x));
```

If files still has items after the removal of "duplicates", I populate lst_files

```
lst_files.Items.AddRange(files.ToArray());
```

This all works up until this point.

Now, due to a need for filters, I have added an Enum nist_type

```
internal enum nist_type
{
    add = 0
    ,
    update = 1
    ,
    delete = 2
}
```

The purpose of the Enum is to determine which record types I need to extract from each individual text file.  So now, when I populate lst_files, I do

```
lst_files.Items.AddRange
(
    files
    .Select(s => "[" + String.Join("][", criteria.nist_types) + "] " + s)
    .ToArray()
);
```

In lst_files, it results to (if all three filers were selected)

```
[add][update][delete] C:\migration\TestFiles\New Text Document.txt
```

The output result in lst_files is perfect, nothing wrong with that.  **Also note that, the prefix to the files can be any combination of [add][update][delete]; it could be one of the three, any two, or all three.**

The problem I am having is checking files, whether the item already exists in lst_files, because of the [add][update][delete] prefix.  I have tried various approaches, but cannot seem to crack this one.  Here I have tried to remove items if it ends with the item in files, but this doesn't work either

```
files.RemoveAll(x => lst_files.Items.Contains(lst_files.Items.Cast<string>().Where(s => s.EndsWith(x))));
```

I know I can do it in a for loop which would be quite easy, but I would much rather do it the more elegant LINQ way and learn something new.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm trying this, it's work fine :

```
files.RemoveAll(x => lst_files.Items.Cast<string>().Any(s => s.EndsWith(x)));
```

> For test, i used :

```
internal enum nist_type
{
    add = 0,
    update = 1,
    delete = 2
}

List<string> files = new List<string>() { "C:\\migration\\TestFiles\\New Text Document.txt" };
string[] lst_files = files.Select(s => "[" + String.Join("][", new List<nist_type> { nist_type.add, nist_type.update }) + "] " + s).ToArray();

files.RemoveAll(x => lst_files.Any(s => s.EndsWith(x)));
```

I hope this will help you fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but it doesn't work for what I am trying to do.  lst_files is a CheckListBox, not an array of string, and the CheckedListBox Items doesn't contain a definition for Any().  Having to create an array from the lst_files items defeats the purpose, then I might as well go the for loop way, which is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: try to ``Cast`` first, and use my suggestion: ``IEnumerable<string> lst_fileList = lst_files.Items.Cast<string>(); files.RemoveAll(x => lst_fileList.Any(s => s.EndsWith(x)));`` like my update. for your code, you try to check if ``ObjectCollection`` contains ``string`` will give always ``false``.

Comment: However... and I was just about to post when I saw your comment.  I changed your second line of code and added a cast, and then it works perfectly.  I used files.RemoveAll(x => lst_files.Items.Cast<string>().Any(s => s.EndsWith(x)));  if you update your answer I will mark it as accepted.  Again thanks for your help.